# Spring session unable save session to Redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I have an application that is integrated with spring security. I separated this application to two app for this I want to config spring session with Redis for centralization authentication between this two app. I have configured Redis but when I want to log in the below exception is raised:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:
>   Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception
>   is java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:90)
>   ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na]     ... 35 common frames
>   omitted
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_111]

The RedisConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisConfig implements BeanClassLoaderAware {

    private ClassLoader loader;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(redisTemplate.getStringSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class));
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID"); // <1>
        serializer.setCookiePath("/"); // <2>
        serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"); // <3>
        return serializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModules(SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(this.loader));
        return mapper;
    }

    public void setBeanClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.loader = classLoader;
    }
}
```

and this config:

```
public class SafeDeserializationRepository<S extends ExpiringSession> implements SessionRepository<S> {

    private final SessionRepository<S> delegate;
    private final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate;

    private static final String BOUNDED_HASH_KEY_PREFIX = "spring:session:sessions:";
    // private static final Logger logger =
    // getLogger(SafeDeserializationRepository.class);

    public SafeDeserializationRepository(SessionRepository<S> delegate, RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public S createSession() {
        return delegate.createSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(S session) {
        delegate.save(session);
    }

    @Override
    public S getSession(String id) {
        try {
            return delegate.getSession(id);
        } catch (SerializationException e) {
            // logger.info("Deleting non-deserializable session with key {}",
            // id);
            redisTemplate.delete(BOUNDED_HASH_KEY_PREFIX + id);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String id) {
        delegate.delete(id);
    }
}
```

and  RedisSessionConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisSessionConfig extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate;

  @Bean
  @Override
  public <S extends ExpiringSession> SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends ExpiringSession> springSessionRepositoryFilter(SessionRepository<S> sessionRepository) {
    return super.springSessionRepositoryFilter(new SafeDeserializationRepository<>(sessionRepository, redisTemplate));
  }
}
```

What is wrong?

I am confused

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar issue few weeks ago.Please check the classes. You can use the java's `implements Serializable` for those classes. The issue is encountered when the class is not Serializable. Also look in the Jackson annotations so that you can choose how object will be serialized.